# Is it possible to code an "access clipboard" monitoring program?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, clipboard, malware

Is there any possibility on Windows to create a programm ( C# or even C++, or any other language) which can be able to trace which process are using the clipboard ?

I have a malware who modify my clipboard when i paste ethereum adresses. No tools are able to detect this malware...since i'm programmer i would like to code a tool to help me to find the malicious process.

Any idea if it's possible ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: "I have a malware who modify my clipboard when i paste ethereum adresses. No tools are able to detect this malware" - the ***only*** sane way of handling this situation is: completely wipe and reinstall the system. period.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann - I'm afraid to ask about your cure for a headache :)

Comment: @VladFeinstein for a regular headache: clean, fresh air, rest, and if neccessary mild painkillers. it's not like a headache can hide somewhere deep in your brain and you'll never be sure if you actually eradicated it or not, always leaving open the possibility of it making you blurt out your most private memories, or replicating itself to other people undetected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Win32 API for monitoring *access* to the clipboard, only for detecting when changes are made to the clipboard's content.

To do what you are asking for, you will have to write a DLL that directly hooks the Win32 [`OpenClipboard()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-openclipboard) function, such as with a [detour](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours), and then you can inject that DLL into all running processes, such as with [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw), [`AppInit_DLLs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/win7appqual/appinit-dlls-in-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2), etc.  When your hook is called, it can communicate information about the calling process back to your main app as needed, such as the [process ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocessid).

Answer (score 2):

You can find an existing and reputable tool that can do that for you:
[Sysmon v12.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysmon) by SysInternals.

Although it doesn't mention it on the doc page, [this](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-sysmon-now-logs-data-copied-to-the-windows-clipboard/) states

> Sysmon 12 adds clipboard capturing

I sifted through some help and references and confirmed that the following config works:

```
  <Sysmon schemaversion="4.40">
  <CaptureClipboard />
  <EventFiltering>
    <RuleGroup name="" groupRelation="or">
      <ClipboardChange onmatch="exclude">
      </ClipboardChange>
    </RuleGroup>
  </EventFiltering>
</Sysmon>
```

You can view those captured events in the Windows Event Viewer, in

`Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Sysmon/Operational`.

In response to my copying text from the command prompt, I can see this logged event:

```
Clipboard changed:
RuleName: -
UtcTime: 2020-10-12 22:08:45.505
ProcessGuid: {0509ed25-cd58-5f84-41a3-050000003500}
ProcessId: 20708
Image: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
Session: 3
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, for DIY programmers :)

From your code, copy something to the Clipboard with delay rendering:

```
::SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, NULL);
```

When someone (that malware?) would attempt to get that text, you will receive a `WM_RENDERFORMAT` message. If you place a breakpoint there and stop your execution, the calling program will be blocked on its `GetClipboardData` call or something like that.

I didn't figure out where to go from here. Enumerate all processes? Attach to each one with Debugger? Look at their call stack?